# Calculating the space complexity of for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, space-complexity

I have a piece of code of which space complexity is to be calculated in Big-O notation

```
 int a = 0, b = 0;    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a = a + rand();  
    }
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        b = b + rand();
    }
```

The `rand()` is an O(1) space.

I think the answer should be O(max(M,N)) but the answer in my textbook is O(1).
Shouldn't the space depend on N and M?

Comment: N, M are constants. They don't change. Also you seem to confuse space with time. There is no extra space here used. Space is used when you allocate some memory to store intermediate results etc.

Comment: `a` and `b` are both  of type Int32. Their size is independent of N and M. Thus space complexity is O(1).

Comment: The only space taken are by variables a, b, M, N which is constant and hence O(1). The runtime is dependent on the values of M and N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space complexity here does not depend on N and M. Space complexity depends on `int` so the **Space Complexity** is `O(1)`.
**Time Complexity** is `O(max(M,N))` and `O(n)` is just enough, no need for too much details (i mean here on max(M,N))

Comment: fwiw, even including the details it is `O(N)`. For any fixed `M` and `N` you can find a constant `k` such that `M == k*N`, then `O( max(M,N)) == O( max(k*N,N)) == O(N)`